# Deactivate Scrollbar

Tags: webdynpro

I've implemented a custom Web-Dynpro ABAP Application, which is called in our portal. I've got the problem, that in different browsers Application is behaving differently.

In this application we only display 8 radio buttons ( its more likely to have 4 or 6 ) in one group. Scrollbar is disabled by default in the WDA Application.

My problem is, that the scrollbar does appear in chrome / chromium edge - but in IE it does not ( which is correct ).

[image: WDA Application in Chrome]

Is there anything I can do to deactivate the scrollbar? I wasn't able to find a note.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the scrollmode of your transparent container?

Comment: @Suncatcher it is set to "None". I've tried a bit with custom CSS ( I think the attribute in the WD-Element is called "customStyleClass" or something like this ( would need to look it up now ) ) but this only gave me dumps...